# Rails route alias for a nested route with specific id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I am trying to make some alias for my rails route like this `'events/8/event_participants/new'` to `/business-meet/registration`,
My routes are written like this:

```
  resources :events, only: [], shallow: true do
    resources :event_participants, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update] do
      post :complete, on: :collection

      member do
        get :invite, :add_people, :accept_invitation, :invitation_success, :reserved
        put :refer
      end
    end
  end
```

I want the alias for the specific event id 8, I tried with `redirect`, but it actually redirect to the the route, so the whole route is visible in the browser, I want the to keep visible `/business-meet/registration` routes to my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `match` method in your route.

```
match '/business-meet/registration', to: 'event_participants#new', via: :get, defaults: { event_id: 8 }
```

Comment: I do not have any events controller as I do not have to do any operation in events, It is giving this error `Routing Error uninitialized constant Events`, event if I make empty EventsController it is not working

Comment: Then how do you know the event? You can remove the events from the route. I’ve updated the answer.

Comment: You can see how my route is defined for that part in my question

Comment: I still can’t see your controller and which param 8 is matched to. Did the update not work? I think you need to tweak it to match your code but this is the answer as to how you do it.